# Fire in hot air oven

Tags: drying

We are setting our hot air oven 130 degree Celsius.Unfortunately oven was fired and all the products (wheat flour) are burnt.What is the reason for this type of fire?

Comment: Hi Haskerali, welcome to the site! Could you please provide more details? 130C is a low setting. Was there something in the oven? What were the materials also inside the oven? For how long was the oven on? Is this an old oven? Have you ever used this oven?

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying that there was an explosion while you attempted to dry/bake plain loose flour in a fan-assisted oven, then I'd say it was a classic **[dust explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_explosion)** (flour explosion). It occurs when fine dust of combustible material (the flour) is dispersed in the air (e.g. by air whirling) and then gets ignited by an open flame, a heat element, or even an electrostatic discharge. This can happen at any temperature. Flour explosions are a [known workplace hazard in the food industries and grain/flour storage facilities.](http://www.hse.gov.uk/food/dustexplosion.htm)

Next time turn off fan-assisted heating in your oven. If not possible, use a different oven.